# Angular material theme install

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm beginning with Angular material.After install dependencies I can use the components but cant't see any colors.

First I've installed the theme at styles.css :

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css";
```

But witth no results.

Then I used a reference at index.html :

```
  <link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

No results too. All remains black and white.

Any ideas ?

Comment: are you using angular-cli ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you set a color attribute to your component like e.g.

```
<button md-raised-button color="primary">Click me!</button>
```

This should normally result in a colored button:

[image]

Comment: Hi Phillip, completely normal and colored as yours.I think the problem was related with the component that I was testing ( the menu ) that is really black and white. From you sample I tested now several others components and all are normal ( colored ).Thank you

Answer (score 3):

please tell more about your project, which version of angular? surely you are doing wrong, if it's angular cli project, you need to add in in .angular-cli.json, you should see a property named styles, add it there

Comment: Shure. 

@angular/cli: 1.4.2
node: 6.10.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.3
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.10
@angular/common: 4.3.6
@angular/compiler: 4.3.6
@angular/core: 4.3.6
@angular/forms: 4.3.6
@angular/http: 4.3.6
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.10
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.6
@angular/router: 4.3.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.6
typescript: 2.2.2

Comment: and did you add it to styles in angular-cli.json and run 'ng serve'?

Comment: can I have your code? app.module, style.css, angular-cli.json, app.component.html? not all of your project, I did it now and it works for me.

Comment: Hi @Faisal , I think the problem was related with the component that I was testing ( the menu ) that is really black and white. Thank you !

Comment: Hi @StetHD .I think the problem was related with the component that I was testing ( the menu ) that is really black and white. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

In your `.angular-cli.json` add the following in your `styles` entry:

```
styles: [
    "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
]
```

then run `ng build` in your terminal window.

Comment: I did that but with no results.

Comment: no need of "../". change the path to "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"